# Is a "Perfect" Vacuum theoretically possible

Tags: vacuum

I came across this answer to another stack exchange question and wondered about how true the claim was. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/174683/42787

It starts with a disclaimer that claims that

> A perfect vacuum is impossible

Now I know that perfect absolute zero is a theoretical impossibility because of many theories regarding quantum physics make it so, namely it's impossible to know the position and momentum of atoms at the same time: If they weren't moving you'd know where they were and that they had no momentum. So making something totally absolute zero is impossible. However is there a similar (or even dissimilar) theoretical impossibility regarding a perfect vacuum. If there were no atoms in the space then you'd have nothing to know the position and momentum of.

Because of this question: [Why is it impossible to have a perfect vacuum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/161107/why-is-it-impossible-to-have-a-perfect-vacuum) (and the fact the answers are a little ambiguous anyway) I'm more loosely defining a vacuum as a space that has absolutely no complete atoms or perhaps, if it makes it actually practical to answer, molecules in it at all, ignoring zero point energy, radiation etc.

Lets also assume that the space is defined by a solid container. One that hypothetically doesn't degrade.

I'm not saying that it would be easy, ensuring no residual atoms were present would be practically impossible I'm sure but I see no reason why it would be theoretically impossible. Granted I'm not in any kind of physics related field so my knowledge is rudimentary at best.

Comment: Because particles fluctuate into and out of existence due to [quantum fluctuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation).

Comment: I think you need to be careful about interpreting zero point energy as literally pairs of particles springing into existance.

Comment: Yes I do remember this now... **Well damn it matter**, why can't you play nicely :(

Comment: Even nothingness is uncertain, so instead of zero you get somethings.

Comment: @user6760 Could you or someone else provide that as a fleshed out answer?

Comment: You're actually quoting my answer (Also, you can link directly to an answer by clicking the "share" button).  Anyway, don't read _too_ far into what I said; my point was that it is impossible to completely evacuate **all** matter from a container.

Comment: @Sean I thought it was an interesting question, your answer simple created that interest. Soooooo, thanks?

Comment: The outside of the universe. There's no space, no time.

Comment: I'm assuming the outside of our universe is a little beyond our theoretical vision however :P
... Having said that, having a space where no atoms exists _within our universe_ could just as well be the same

Comment: Go to this video link... This will really help...  http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=J3xLuZNKhlY